# How can I pull User IDs from Adobe Analytics for users who match a segment?

Tags: adobe, analytics, connector

I'm trying to lift all the User IDs that match a segment in Adobe Analytics and store them somewhere (anywhere really), so I can then feed them into an action system for targeting.

Documentation seems hard to find - anyone have ideas on how I could achieve this?

Not sure if there's APIs or SDKs that let me pull this data, or pre-built connectors into something like Google Sheets, but again documentation seems light at best.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest tool to use would likely be the [Report Builder](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics/analyze/report-builder/home.html?lang=en). It's an Excel extension by Adobe to export the data. It's pretty powerful. Can do pretty much everything AA can.

You could also generate [data feeds](https://business.adobe.com/products/analytics/data-warehouse.html) and ETL the data from there to wherever you need it. It's a bit more advanced though.

Finally, you have the [customer journey API](https://developer.adobe.com/cja-apis/docs/), which would now be an even more advanced level of ETL.

Otherwise, yes, Adobe is notorious for how bad their documentation is and how hard it is to find it. It's almost like they don't want the good documentation to be there in order to sell more of their certification courses.

Note that sometimes when you google something and get to their forum to see the answer, Adobe will attempt to hide the answer behind the authentication wall. Just open that link in incognito and you'll be good. Adobe is pretty weird.